# Java String to JsonObject returns null

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to convert String to JSONObject, but always returns null.

At front page, I used `$.ajax` to send post data,

```js
    var jsonInfo = '{"search_key":"apple", "person":{"name":"test","age":20}}';
    
    var testApi = $.ajax({
        type : "POST", 
        url : "/test/testPerson",
        dataType : "json",
        data : {
            "apiData" : JSON.stringify(jsonInfo)
        }
    })
    .done(function(data, status){
        console.log("success!" + status);
    });
```

At Servlet, I tried to get the JSONObject with following code :

```java
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object obj = null;
    try {
        obj = parser.parse(reqApiKey2);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
```

But I got an error, `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject` at `jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;`

I tried to send the data with `JSON.parse(jsonInfo)` from web, but same result.

Thank you for your advices, and helps.

Comment: I recommend you to use in java the library of Google Gson  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson

It's really easy to use

Comment: Why are you calling `JSON.stringify(jsonInfo)`? It's *already* json! By calling that, the json gets sent as a plain String. There's nothing wrong with your server code; it is behaving correctly.

Comment: @Bohemian because I think it could be the problem.. T^T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client code is turning the json in the variable `jsonInfo` into a plain String. Don't do that - it's *already* JSON!

Change:

```
data : {
    "apiData" : JSON.stringify(jsonInfo)
}
```

to:

```
data : {
    "apiData" : jsonInfo
}
```

Your server code is correctly deserializing it as `String`, not an object.